# Problems querying subdocuments in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

This is what I'm working with:

```
{
    "_id" : "81sYXOs_mW",
    "comentarios" : [ 
        {
            "id" : "2326994",
            "nomeu" : "chriscastanho",
            "texto" : "Parece que se move"
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "20981686",
            "nomeu" : "arthurmartinez",
            "texto" : "@carolinacauzzo olha que demais"
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "2210548605",
            "nomeu" : "ademilson.baluta",
            "texto" : "Será o fim? ????????????"
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "14222758",
            "nomeu" : "velmakelly",
            "texto" : "@tudo_bele o sol tambem ta ficando careca, nao é so voce"
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "418674188",
            "nomeu" : "fabianofofano",
            "texto" : "No Brasil o fim já começou...#Impeachment"
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "410264740",
            "nomeu" : "lucianah_oliveiraa",
            "texto" : "Isso é normal?"
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "11397971",
            "nomeu" : "helen.jpeg",
            "texto" : "@helenlacerda01 olha que impressionante a foto do sol!"
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "144821378",
            "nomeu" : "innyaraujo",
            "texto" : "@alinefarias8 !!!!!"
        }
```

What I'm trying to do:

```
db.getCollection('interacoes').find({'comentarios.$.id':'2326994'})
```

This is just an example, I want to look on the field id or text and that the query return only the fields that match my criteria. However it seems that it's not working, because returns 0 results. I'm using '$' because there a lot of sub documents from 0 to 50 id.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to filter the documents based on a field inside the *comentarios*, you should remove the *$*.
This should work:

```
db.getCollection('interacoes').find({'comentarios.id':'2326994'})
```

If you want also to return, inside the *comentarios*, only the sub-documents that match the criteria, a solution I see is using the aggregation:

```
 pipeline =[{"$match": {'comentarios.id': '2326994'}},
        {"$addFields": {"comentarios": {"$filter": {
                    "input": "$comentarios",
                    "cond": {"$eq": ["$$this.id", '2326994']}
                         }} } }]
 db.getCollection('interacoes').aggregate(pipeline)
```